# How to render my view with additional option

Tags: python, django

I can't make my html render my form with additional option.
So I need to make that in my html my `order_form` will be rendered with additional_option that in product. And then place it all in `OrderItem`.
I don't understand what I should do

I ve tryied to make queryset `queryset=product.objects.get(pk  = 6).add_option.all()`
with specific id but in only shows text `QuerySet`

My form

```
class Order_form(forms.Form):
    add_option = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(widget = forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, required = False)
```

model 1

```
class OrderItem(models.Model):
    product = models.OneToOneField(product, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    additional_option = models.ManyToManyField(AdditionalOption)
```

model 2

```
class product(models.Model):
    add_option = models.ManyToManyField(AdditionalOption, blank = True)
```

Comment: It is a bit strange that your `OrderItem` has a `OneToOneField` to `Product`. Does that mean that each `Product` can be ordered only *once*?

Comment: yep. 1 product to 1 order item that than will be puted in order.

Comment: Can you show the html and the view where are you using this form?